# What should be the ideal threshold on array size in order to use a non-recursive sorting method?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, language-agnostic

I recently did a revision on sorting algorithms. While revisioning, I imagined some code that selects the optimal of two available sorting algorithms to sort an array, according to array's size. For example, it has to choose between `insertion sort` and `quicksort`.

It's well known that `quicksort` is used extensively to sort large arrays and that achieves its average case time, that is `O(nlogn)`, although its worst-case time is `O(n^2)`. On the other hand, `insertion sort` isn't recursive, thus it may consume less CPU time when it sorts a small-sized array. So, what should be a nice threshold size for the aforementioned code in order to choose the most efficient of those algorithms?

Other performance factors, like "how close" is a given sequence to its sorted permutation, aren't concerning me right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From Princeton University's quicksort page](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/23quicksort/)

> Cutoff to insertion sort. As with mergesort, it pays to switch to
>   insertion sort for tiny arrays. The optimum value of the cutoff is
>   system-dependent, but any value between 5 and 15 is likely to work
>   well in most situations.

I personally prefer a cut off size of 15. But again that is system dependent and may or may not be the best in your case.

Comment: What a nice explanation of quicksort's function you gave me! A threshold of 15 seems rational, although I expected a much higher value, about 40-50.